# How can I have superscript footnote numbers in the body and full sized numbers beneath the text?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

Following the suggested practice in Bringhurst, I want my footnote markers to be superscript in the text, but in the footnote block, the same size and positioning as the rest of the footnote text. So for example:

> `example.docx`
>
> This is a sentence.<sup>1</sup>

> ---
>
> 1. This is the reference

Can this be done in Microsoft Word?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the reference number in the footer

[image]

Right click on it and choose "Style..." from the popup menu

[image]

Select "Footnote Text" from the list of Styles

[image]

Click OK. The result:

[image]

Comment: This works but is not automatic. There is no Automatic method that I know of. You could write a macro that would do this for all footnotes.

Answer (score 0):

To add a little more to cybernetic.nomad answer - for convenience, you can assign a short key to the "Footnote Text" style by modifying it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).